# iOS - Wordpress Swift SDK?

Tags: ios, swift, wordpress

I'm building an app and I'd like to use Wordpress as the backend for my users. For example, I want my app user to be able to login to their account that they registered on my Wordpress site, and then post to and from it from my native application. Does Wordpress have a swift SDK that allows me to do this?

Comment: Wordpress has a REST api. You can call it from Swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make REST requests and auth too. Take a look here https://wpengine.com/resources/using-wordpress-rest-api-plugin/

On Swift side you can use Alamofire for communication.

Also if you want more API routes you should install some of API/REST WP plugin

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Set it up with Alamofire this morning and it works like a charm!